# Read a file into a string, then split the string by the "/" character, and put the results into a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a text file which includes this:

```
Test/Test Lane
Jack/Fake Road
```

So far I have this:

```
with open ("address.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
print(data)
```

However, when I print "data" all I get is this:

```
Test/Test LaneJack/Fake Road
```

I'm glad this bit works, but how would I now split the string by the "/" character, and input this into a dictionary?

Comment: what would ur dicctionary look like

Comment: @vks Well, it would need to be something like (using the example addresses I have) `details = {"Test": "Test Lane", "Jack": "Fake Road"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over your lines and split with `/`:

```
>>> dict(line.strip().split('/') for line in open("address.txt", "r"))
{'Test': 'Test Lane', 'Jack': 'Fake Road'}
```

Comment: this works, but it still has the "/n" on every other string. How would I remove this?

Comment: @String yeah, you need to remove `\n` with `strip()`!

Comment: Note this will break if there isn't exactly *one* `/` in the line

Comment: @JonClements It works by having a name, then a "/", then an address, then a new line, so there will never be two "/"'s on any one line, will this be ok?

Comment: @JonClements Yes, its true and it could break for many another occasions too :) but i answered for this case!

Comment: @String as long as there's always a single `/` - it'll work - and if it does break, then that's good, because you'll get an exception which will indicate you've got a line that's not in the correct format :)

Comment: @Kasra so how would I do this? On the same line (at the end)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
k=file.readlines()
print dict(re.findall(r"^([^/]*)\/(.*)$",k,re.MULTILINE))
```